# How to put and get a list of strings to Bundle in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, android-bundle, android-savedstate

Assume there is list of strings like

```
val list = listOf("a", "b")
```

How do I save it into and get from Bundle in Kotlin?

I've tried saving like this but it gives the type mismatch error

```
outState.putStringArrayList(KEY, list.toTypedArray())

Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch
Required: ArrayList<String!>?
Found: Array<String>
```

Comment: `outState.putStringArray(KEY, list.toTypedArray())`

Comment: Or start with `val list = arrayListOf("a", "b")`. Then `outState.putStringArrayList(KEY, list)`

Comment: Drawn Raccoon, your solution works for me. Thank you!